# How to change the system variable in Geoserver

Tags: environment-variables, size, shapefile, geoserver

I'm on Linux.I'm using postgresql - geoserver - openlayers.
I want to display a shapefile with GeoServer. I store it in Postgresql and import the table on Geoserver. The size of the shapefile is 2.2GB.
When I want to display my shapefile with the Openlayers viewer (on Geoserver), I have a white screen and this error is the logs:

*ERROR [geoserver.ows] org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering process failed ....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not write to tuplestore temporary file: No space left on device where: SQL function "st_force_2d" statement 2*

I saw here: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html, that's the limit size is 2GB for shapefile but we can modify this limit changing the system variables GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE. 
How can I do that ? I checked on Internet but impossible to find a solution.

Comment: Your disk is full, it is nothing to do with the shapefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you mentioned it said:

> it’s possible to modify those limits by setting the GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE and GS_DBF_MAX_SIZE system variables to a different value.

So I think it's similar to `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` config.

**For binaries installation**: You should change OS system variables. I'm not sure but, the command is something like this:

```
$ export GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE=Limit of .shp size in bytes
$ export GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE=3000000000
```

If it didn't work search for changing system var in your Linux dist.

**For web archive installation**: You should change the webserver or GeoServer configuration. There are 2 ways of doing it:

1. Context parameter: Find and edit `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder. then add this context parameter at root element(`<web-app>` tag)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>Limit of .shp size in bytes</param-value>
</context-param>
```

2. Java system property: It's very similar to binaries installation except you should add system variable for the webserver. If you are using tomcat add this to your system variables.

```
$ export CATALINA_OPTS="-GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE=Limit of .shp size in bytes"
$ export CATALINA_OPTS="-GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE=3000000000"
```

*Be careful about changing java system property! it will effect whole Apache tomcat and might cause problem in other web apps installed.*

Comment: Thank you for reply.
When I do printenv in my console, there is no GS_SHP_MAX_SIZE variable.
I installed Geoserver with a web archive....

Comment: @DamTan web archive solution added to answer. hope helps